# How to run multiple ffmpeg tasks in php shell_exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am trying to do the below tasks.

1. Convert video from webm to mp4 format
2. Resize the video
3. Add watermark to the bottom right
4. Generate the thumbnail

I am able to do it by running multiple shell commands. Is there a way to do all four tasks in one go. For example

```
$watermark = "https://dummyimage.com/150x50/bf1fbf/ffffff.png";
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i test.webm -vf scale=100:-1, {$watermark} -filter_complex overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h) test.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 test.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single instance of `-filter_complex` to do all filtering:

```
$watermark = "https://dummyimage.com/150x50/bf1fbf/ffffff.png";
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i test.webm -i '{$watermark}' -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=100:-2[bg];[1]rotate=-3*PI/180[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h):format=auto,format=yuv420p,split=outputs=2[vid][img]' -map '[vid]' -map 0:a test.mp4 -map '[img]' -ss 00:00:01.000 -frames:v 1 test.jpg");
```

- See [FFmpeg Filtering Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).
- Your `ffmpeg` must have support for the HTTPS protocol to use HTTPS inputs. See `ffmpeg -protocols` to check. Otherwise, download the PNG first before running `ffmpeg`.

#### Explanation of the filtergraph

- `[0:v]scale=100:-2[bg]` - Take video from input #0 (`[0:v]`), [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to 100 pixels wide, auto-scale height to preserve aspect, but make sure it is divisible by 2 (a requirement of libx264). Label the scale output `[bg]` (you can give it any name).
- `[1]rotate=-3*PI/180[fg]` Rotate input #1 (`[1]`) by -3 degrees. Name this `[fg]`.
- `[bg][fg]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h):format=auto` - [Overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) `[bg]` under `[fg]`. Place overlay in bottom right. `format` option allows it to auto select an appropriate pixel format for best quality.
- `format=yuv420p` Use [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to make pixel format yuv420p. This is for chroma-subsampling compatibility as non-FFmpeg based players can only support YUV 4:2:0 H.264.
- `split=outputs=2[vid][img]` [Split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) the output from the filtering into two identical streams named `[vid]` and `[img]`. This is required when making two outputs using the same filtered output because you can't re-use the same filter output more than once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. You mentioned a very good point regarding protocol. Yes, my ffmpeg supports https. Can you please explain the command a little bit. I noticed you used format as well.

Comment: Btw I just executed the code and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @AwaisZahid You need to first determine if the issue is the PHP code, or with the ffmpeg command, or both. It is always recommended to run the command in your terminal first (unscripted) to make sure it works before adding it to your code. Also, "does not seem to work" is never as helpful and informative as providing the errors.

Comment: First I apologize secondly I greatly appreciate the detailed explanation.  Basically this is the only line of code I have on my PHP file and it runs silently. What I can assure is ffmpeg is operational on the server because when I run a single filter it works. I am sure there is no PHP error otherwise it will generate an error_log file. I am not sure if I can enable logs for ffmpeg. I am accessing it on a VPS through the web browser. Makes sense?

Comment: I wrapped two parts of the code in single quotes and it works. `shell_exec("ffmpeg -i test.webm -i '{$watermark}' -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=360:-2[bg];[bg][1]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h),format=yuv420p,split=outputs=2[vid][img]' -map [vid] test.mp4 -map [img] -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 test.jpg");` Though I do not understand why it was breaking without '

Comment: @AwaisZahid Depending on your language/shell/code the filtergraph may need to be quoted to escape the parenthesis and other special characters. But I am not a PHP user and did not know if it needed that. I will update answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. The updated answer works! I have two quick questions please. 1. Is it possible to improve the quality of the overlay? The video seems to be of good quality but the overlay image losses the quality. 2. I am trying to rotate the overlay image `rotate=-3*PI/180` is it correct?

Comment: @AwaisZahid 1. Overlay quality can be improved by adding `format=auto` to overlay filter (this is different than format filter). See updated example. 2. Yes, that will rotate the image -3 degrees.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Seems like it breaks the moment I add format=auto. The updated code stopped working :(

Comment: @AwaisZahid With no info I can only guess that your ffmpeg is ancient.

Comment: It says I have ffmpeg version 2.8.15

Comment: @AwaisZahid See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for links to already compiled recent ffmpeg for your OS.

Comment: Man, you are a rockstar!!! I updated ffmpeg and it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: I just noticed that the output video has no audio even we do not have -an flag. What could be the reason, please?

Comment: @AwaisZahid You are only mapping the video output from the filtergraph. You need to add `-map 0:a` output option. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: Got it. Thank you. If you please update the answer it would be very helpful to other viewers.